# How to get correct text element in XML file

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing

I have the following xml child looking as follows:

```
<RollCallVote.Description.Text>
Agence européenne des médicaments - European Medicines Agency - Europäische Arzneimittel-Agentur -
<a href="#reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216" data-rel="reds" redmap-uri="/reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216">A9-0216/2021</a>
- Nicolás González Casares - Accord provisoire - Am 156
</RollCallVote.Description.Text>
```

Now I try to get the following two elements, the `redcap-uri` text `A9-0216/2021`and the text behind that `Nicolás González Casares - Accord provisoire - Am 156`, ideally in two pandas data frame columns.

Unfortunately,

```
for adescription in avote.iter('RollCallVote.Description.Text'):
        description = adescription.get('a')
```

the data frame column in the end only gives me `redcap-uri`but not the text for it. Also changing it to `description = adescription.get('a').text` does not work, as I get the error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

If I use

```
for adescription in avote.iter('RollCallVote.Description.Text'):
        description = adescription.text
```

the beginning of the text, meaning `Agence européenne des médicaments - European Medicines Agency - Europäische Arzneimittel-Agentur -`, is displayed in the end but nothing else.

Can someone please help to solve this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ElementTree texts of interest could be extracted as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

content = '''<root>
<RollCallVote.Description.Text>
Agence européenne des médicaments - European Medicines Agency - Europäische Arzneimittel-Agentur -
<a href="#reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216" data-rel="reds" redmap-uri="/reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216">A9-0216/2021</a>
- Nicolás González Casares - Accord provisoire - Am 156
</RollCallVote.Description.Text>
<RollCallVote.Description.Text>
Agence européenne des médicaments - European Medicines Agency - Europäische Arzneimittel-Agentur -
<a href="#reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216" data-rel="reds" redmap-uri="/reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216">A9-0217/2021</a>
- Nicolás González Casares - Accord provisoire - Am 157
</RollCallVote.Description.Text>
<RollCallVote.Description.Text>
Agence européenne des médicaments - European Medicines Agency - Europäische Arzneimittel-Agentur -
<a href="#reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216" data-rel="reds" redmap-uri="/reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216">A9-0218/2021</a>
- Nicolás González Casares - Accord provisoire - Am 158
</RollCallVote.Description.Text>
</root>'''

# create a dict to store temporary data
dct = defaultdict(list)

# parse XML
root = ET.fromstring(content)

# find elements with the given name
elements = root.findall('RollCallVote.Description.Text')

# iterate over elements found
for element in elements:
  # search for 'a' element having attribute 'redmap-uri'
  # if there is only one 'a' child element predictae can be omitted
  link = element.find('a[@redmap-uri]')
  if link:
      dct['link'].append(link.text)
      dct['text'].append(link.tail)

# construct pandas dataframe from a dict
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

df
```

Comment: I tried to adapt it to my already existing code as ```for adescription in avote.iter('RollCallVote.Description.Text'):
        description_data = adescription.find('a[@redmap-uri]')
        description_filename = description_data.text
        description_type = description_data.tail``` however, now I get the error message ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ```... is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It seems, that some elements `RollCallVote.Description.Text` do not have `a` children. In case both description_filename and description_type should be skipped, just a check for existence should be added. If description_filename should be skipped, but description_type should be parsed, logic would be more complex. I updated the answer with the check for an `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract some text from well-formatted xml code in a column (always the same structure), you can also try to solve it using regex instead of an xml parser:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"text": """<RollCallVote.Description.Text>
Agence européenne des médicaments - European Medicines Agency - Europäische Arzneimittel-Agentur -
<a href="#reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216" data-rel="reds" redmap-uri="/reds:iPlRp/A-9-2021-0216">A9-0216/2021</a>
- Nicolás González Casares - Accord provisoire - Am 156
</RollCallVote.Description.Text>
"""}, index=[0])

df["text"].str.extract(r'(.*?)\n<a .*>(.*?)<\/a>\n(.*?)\n<\/RollCallVote\.Description\.Text>', expand=True)
```

I just took the text and replaced the interesting parts with `(.*?)` capture groups (`.` is any char, `*` is any amount, so `.*` is any char, any amount. You can probably skip the `?` after `.*`, but I just wanted to make sure it doesn't capture everything, which is what the `?` does. The `()` brackets are a capture group, which is transformed to a column by .str.extract) and adding line breaks (`\n`) and escaping (adding `\`) dots (you need to tell regex if a dot is a dot and not an arbitrary char by writing `\.`).